# Windows phone 8.1 SQLite filenotfound

Tags: c#, sqlite, windows-phone-8.1

I have an application which is active and on the store.

My problem is after the pc's reset, because I had to reinstall every tool and I'm stuck on SQLite.

When I run the application, I got this error:

[image]

I have sqlite extension installed as you can see from here:
[image]

I found some posts saying I have to add the sqlite ref to my project but I don't see it, as tou can see:

[image]

My project was working correctly before the reset, what I'm missing now?

Thanks all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have installed the [Sqlite.vsix](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/5d97faf6-39e3-4048-a0bc-adde2af75d1b) and reference it in your project Now you will need to add nuget package of Sqlite for windows phone 8.1 and you are all set.

Comment: I did the same but I forgot to post the answer, thanks!

Comment: Hopefully answer might help someone else in future. Although chances are slim as with anniversary update now sqlite comes integrated in VS.